# Why does the error struct FILE* but argument is of type char* appear?

Tags: c

I was wondering why I'm getting the error "expected struct FILE* but argument is of type char*"? Is it because I'm passing in a type(string) instead of a type (FILE)? I plan to change the variable char *file_name to FILE *file_name, but what would I do with the %s in scanf?

```
    FILE *read_open_file(char *argv)
    {
         FILE *ifp;
         char *inputFileName = argv[1];
         printf("File name %s",inputFileName);

         ifp = fopen(inputFileName,"r");

         if (ifp == NULL)
         {
              fprintf(stderr,"File %s does not exist",inputFileName);
              exit(1);
         }
         return ifp;


    }





   int main()
   {
       char *file_name;
       printf("Please enter file name: ");
       scanf("%s", &file_name);
       read_open_file(file_name);


      read_command();
      //printf("%c", read_command());
      evaluate_command();

      return 0;
   }
```

Comment: What line are you getting this error on? Also, can you share the exact text?

Comment: I don't think `argv[1]` is doing what you think it's doing. (unrelated to your error)

Comment: I can't see such an error in that portion of code. But there at least a mistake, you didn't allocate any memory for `file_name` in your main. At least declare it as an array or use `malloc`. Also don't use the address of it in `scanf` `file_name` is already an address.

Comment: If you want to use `argv`, you need `int main (int argc, char **argv)` You can then pass it to `read_open_file` if desired.

Comment: `scanf("%s", &file_name);` is a blunder

Answer (score 1):

There are many issue in  your code, likely,

1. In your code

   ```
     char *file_name;
     printf("Please enter file name: ");
     scanf("%s", &file_name);
   ```

   invokes [undefined behavior](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior) as you did not allocate memory to `fine_name` and passing the address of the pointer to `scanf()`. I don't see a reason for `file_name` to be a pointer. Use an array nad change your code like

   ```
     char file_name[64] = {0};
     printf("Please enter file name: ");
     scanf("%63s", file_name);   //save from buffer overflow
   ```
2. Inside `read_open_file()` function, doing

   ```
   char *inputFileName = argv[1];
   ```

   is wrong, as `inputFileName` is a pointer and you're trying to assign a `char` (`argv[1]`) to it. You don't need all this. As you're passing the string containing the file name directly as the argument to the function, inside `read_open_file()`, you can do something like

   ```
    FILE *ifp = NULL;
    printf("File name %s\n",argv);
    ifp = fopen(argv,"r");
   ```

   and get your job done.

Answer (score 1):

After you solve your other issues, you will find you need to assign the return from `read_open_file` to a `FILE*` pointer in `main()`, otherwise, you will have no reference to the file you open in `read_open_file` in `main` -- and you will lose the ability to close the file you opened in `read_open_file`.

Look over the following and let me know if you have questions.

```
#include <stdio.h>

#define FNSZ 128

FILE *read_open_file (char *fn);

int main (void) {

    char file_name[FNSZ] = {0};
    FILE *fp = NULL;

    printf ("Please enter file name: ");
    if (scanf ("%127s%*c", file_name) != 1) {
        fprintf (stderr, "error: file_name entry failed.\n");
        return 1;
    }

    /* you must assign return to FILE* */
    fp = read_open_file (file_name);
    if (!fp) {
        fprintf (stderr, "error: file open failed '%s'\n", file_name);
        return 1;
    }

    /* read/evaluate from here */
    // read_command (...);
    // evaluate_command (...);

    fclose (fp);

    return 0;
}

FILE *read_open_file (char *fn)
{
    FILE *ifp;
    printf ("File name %s\n", fn);

    ifp = fopen (fn, "r");

    if (ifp == NULL)
        fprintf(stderr,"File %s does not exist", fn);

    return ifp;
}
```

Comment: Hi I was wondering for *fn would you need to declare the number of bytes needed like char *fn[1024] for it to act like a string.

Comment: What is the difference between char (pointer)fn[1024], char (pointer)fn, and char fn[1024]?

Comment: char `*fn[1024];` (declares an *array of pointers*, 1024 to type *char*); `char *fn;` (declares a *pointer to type char*); finally `char fn[1024];` (declares an *array* of type *char*, 1024 long). It is critical that you understand the difference. You need to also understand the difference between `char (*fn)[1024];` (a *pointer to an array* of type *char*, 1024) and char `*fn[1024];` (the *array of pointers*).

Answer (score 0):

You are making some mistakes. `argv` in your code is itself a pointer to the filename. So you can use that directly

```
printf("File name %s",argv);
ifp = fopen(argv,"r");
```